# How to make an Imagebutton change Image onClick in and Back to its original on ClickOut in Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android

So I have some Images of buttons that I created and I want to use them in android studio as ImageButtons.

[image]

Basically I want the ImageButton OnClick in to change its Image and OnClick out to return to its first Image.

I am trying this:

```
    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            goalsButton.setBackground(R.drawable.mygoalsclicked);

        }
    };
```

But I get the error:

**In View cannot be applied to (Int)**

Can that be done in Android Studio? And how? Does any one knows?
Thank you.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Ok edited my question: With how? :D

Comment: _Ok edited my question..._ Still not a valid request on StackOverflow as we do not provide any free code writing services. Modify your question with some piece of code to get better help

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ToggleButton
Instead ImageView

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   <!--check.xml-->
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

check.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use first Image -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/achievement"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected,  use second Image-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/achievementclicked"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are You Looking for?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_selector" />
```

image_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/achievementclicked" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/achievement" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the onClick method you have to put this code:

ImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);

Comment: I get this error: Non-static method 'setImageResource(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Try to declare the ImageButton as final

Comment: Don't use upper-case naming for variables. It's against naming conventions, and causes issues like that without an obvious cause if the field doesn't exist.